# SQLite GetChar returns null

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a simple SQLite table:

```
CREATE TABLE "Phones" ("Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , ... , "Type" CHAR(1) NOT NULL )
```

However, when I try to retrieve values everything comes up as expected except the "Type".  "Type" is always NULL.

Here's the C# code:

```
var phoneType = reader.GetChar(reader.GetOrdinal("Type"))
```

However, if instead of GetChar I use GetString it works as expected:

```
var phoneType = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Type"))[0]
```

The obviouse question is what I'm doing wrong when I use GetChar()?

Comment: What's the value of reader.GetOrdinal("Type") ??

Comment: @AzharKhorasany GetOrdianal("Type") returns the ordinal position of the column "Type" in select statement.  For example: In following statement "SELECT Id, Type FROM Phones" GetOrdianal("Type") will return 1 as an ordinal position.  GetOrdinal("Id") would return 0.

Comment: Is Type a keyword in SQLite? Try using some other name and see whether it works.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.getchar.aspx) says:

> No conversions are performed; therefore the data retrieved must already be a character or coercible to a character.

`CHAR(1)` is not a single character, it is a string that contains a single character.

(Please note in SQLite, charactes are always part of a string; using the type `CHAR` [would behave the same](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).)

Comment: I saw the same documentation before I submit the question.  My question is not about SQLite CHAR type.  It's a question about SQLite ADO.NET adopter.  GetChar methods is inside SQLiteDataReader which derives from DbDataReader.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getchar(v=vs.110).aspx